# how to know from gmail/fb login form that user has successfully logged in, while log in with gmail/fb?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, facebook, twitter-bootstrap, omniauth

Rails 4 + Twitter Bootstrap + jquery + javascript + Ominiauth

_header.html.erb

```
<span class="callno"><%= link_to "Sign in", {:controller => "web",:action => "sign_in_user"}, :role => 'button', 'data-toggle' => 'modal', 'data-target' => '#popup_div', :remote => true %></span>
```

web_controller.rb

```
  def sign_in_user

  end
```

sign_in_user.js.erb

```
    $('#popup_div').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'web/login_form') %>");
```

_login_form.html.erb

```
    <div style="border-right: 1px solid #C0C0C0; margin-left: -11px; float: left; height: 252px"></div>
      <h4>Sign In with</h4></br>
      <a><%= link_to image_tag("web/fb_login.png", :alt => "facebook", :style => 'margin: 0 0 10% 20%'), user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook), :class => "popup", :"data-width" => 600, :"data-height" => 400, :onclick => "return closeloginform();" %> </a><br/><br/>
      <a><%= link_to image_tag("web/google_login.png", :alt => "google", :style => 'margin: 0 0 0 20%'), user_omniauth_authorize_path(:google_oauth2), :class => "popup", :"data-width" => 600, :"data-height" => 500, :onclick => "return closeloginform();" %></a><br/><br/>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">

  function closeloginform(){
    $('#popup_div').modal('hide');
  }

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function popupCenter(url, width, height, name) {
    var left = (screen.width/2)-(width/2);
    var top = (screen.height/2)-(height/2);
    childWindow = window.open(url, name, "menubar=no,toolbar=no,status=no,width="+width+",height="+height+",toolbar=no,left="+left+",top="+top);
    return childWindow;
  }

  $("a.popup").click(function(e) {
    popupCenter($(this).attr("href"), $(this).attr("data-width"), $(this).attr("data-height"), "authPopup");
    e.stopPropagation(); return false;
});
</script>
```

1) On Header Sign In Link is there.

2) When i will click on Sign in it will open a modal popup (twitter bootstrap).

3) There Two options will be there for google(image LOGO) and facebook(image LOGO) sign in.

4) when you will click on any one (suppose google image means sign in with gmail account) then a window will open with gmail login form.

5) There i will enter login details then **What should happen after successful login** child window should close with reloading the parent window. **What is happening after successful login** only child window is reloading and getting successfully sign in in child window.

My question how can i know from gmail/fb login form that user has successfully logged in ??

Comment: Is your question your title (*"How to reload parent window from child window?"*) or what you call your question at the end (*"how can i know from gmail/fb login form that user has successfully logged in ?"*). Those are not the same question.

Comment: Drat, I answered the wrong question. :-)

Answer (score 0):

> How to reload parent window from child window?

Provided the child and parent are within the same origin, then in the child's code you can do this:

```
opener.location.reload();
```

If they aren't, then the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) will kick in and prevent the cross-origin call. In that case, you can use `postMessage` to tell the parent window to reload:

In the parent:

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
    if (e.origin !== "http://the child window's URL") {
        // Ignore this message, we don't know the sender
        return;
    }
    if (e.data === "reload") {
        location.reload();
    }
}, false);
```

In the child:

```
opener.postMessage("reload", "http://the parent's URL");
```

---

Example:

parent.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Opener</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Open Popup">
<script>
(function() {
    // Shows when this window was (re)loaded
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML = "(Re)loaded on " + new Date();
    document.body.appendChild(p);

    // Hooks up the button to open the popup
    document.querySelector("input").onclick = function() {
        window.open("popup.html", "_blank", "width=500,height=500,menubar=no,toolbar=no");
    };
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

popup.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Popup</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Close">
<script>
document.querySelector("input").onclick = function() {
    if (opener) {
        opener.location.reload(); // <==========
    }
    close();
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder i didn't get this "child and parent are within the same origin" can you explain plz..

Comment: @user3676578: For web pages, the "origin" is the combination of protocol, host, and port. So `http://www.example.com/foo.html` uses `http`, `www.example.com`, and `80` (the default HTTP port). For a parent and child window to talk directly to each other (`opener.location.reload()`), the two pages must be from the same origin. So `http://www.example.com/foo.html` can talk directly to `http://www.example.com/bar.html`, but not to `http://en.example.com/bar.html` (because `en.example.com` is not the same host as `www.example.com`). Changing the protocol or port also makes it "cross-origin".

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder in my code how can i add this same origin policy? can you explain plz...

Comment: @user3676578: You don't. The browser enforces the SOP. Are your parent and child windows from the same origin? Or different ones?

Comment: @user3676578: Then if you just need to refresh the parent from code in the child, that `opener.location.reload()` will do it.

Comment: After return childWindow; how it will execute the opener.location.reload(); @ T.J. Crowder

Comment: @user3676578: As I said above, that code goes in the *child* window, not the parent window.

Comment: childWindow = window.open(url, name, "menubar=no,toolbar=no,status=no,width="+width+",height="+height+",toolbar=no,left="+left+",top="+top);
    childWindow.onunload = function () {
    window.parent.popupClosing()
    }; 

 function popupClosing() {
    alert("In side popup");
    window.close();
    window.location.href = window.location.href;
  }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56019/discussion-between-user3676578-and-t-j-crowder).

Comment: Still Issue is open any suggestion/help highly appreciable.. :)

Comment: @user3676578: I've said `opener` repeatedly above. Why are you using `parent` instead?!?! `opener` != `parent`. I've added an example to the answer.